# AWS SageMaker Studio Lab No space left on devices

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have been trying to resolve this issue for the past weeks.
I am trying to build a relatively small ML project using AWS sage maker studio lab (GPU instance). However, every time i try to install packages i get this error: No space left on devices. I have tried creating new environments, deleting the default environments, but i always get the same error.
Is there a way to clean everything and free up space somehow?

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SageMaker Studio Lab is a *free* product with very limited capabilities for customisation and debugging.

Unfortunately, you are [limited to 15GB of storage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-lab-overview.html#studio-lab-overview-project-compute) in Studio Lab.

To confirm your disk usage, run `df -H` within Studio Lab. If the output does **not** support the storage error you’ve experienced, contact AWS support.

You may wish to switch to Amazon SageMaker Studio for increased capacity. The AWS free tier provides 250 hours of ml.t3.medium instance on Studio notebooks [1](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/) for the first *two months* of use.